# app runs normally on real device and emulator but don't work when generating apk

Tags: flutter

When I run the app on a real device or the emulator it normally works but when I do this `flutter build apk` I get this error What is the cause of this and what to do to solve this error ?

```
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.
         > Could not parse POM http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b
5d1d2d8c8c37.pom
            > Already seen doctype.
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.
         > Could not parse POM http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b
5d1d2d8c8c37.pom
            > Already seen doctype.
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37.
         > Could not parse POM http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b5d1d2d8c8c37/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-b6b54fd60631a3828c2e2c9b079b
5d1d2d8c8c37.pom
            > Already seen doctype.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       ٤٫٣s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it only happens when I try and build for x86. It's weird that I can build and run on the simulator.

I'm trying this:

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform android-x86
```